# Setup has no size in "installed applications" after install4j Setup

Tags: windows, install4j, installed-applications

We are installing our software with install4j. I'm wondering, why the installed application has no "size" in windows control panel - installed applications. Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 7 this is not implemented. I've created an issue for it.